# Why does my MacBook Pro wireless networking stop working?

Tags: mac, wireless-networking, airport

I have a network that looks like this:

- wireless router: 192.168.1.1
- Linux machine: 192.168.1.16 (via cable)
- Mac machine: 192.168.1.17 (via wireless)
- Windows machine: 192.168.1.18 (via wireless)

Occasionally, the Mac's networking will stop working, in that pages won't load, services which rely on network won't work, etc. When this happens, the Linux and Windows machines and router will continue to function normally. If, on the Mac, I go to the Wi-Fi icon in the menu bar and choose 'Turn Wi-Fi Off' followed by 'Turn Wi-Fi On', the wireless networking will start working again.

When the Mac is in this state, the following is true:

- the Mac can ping the router, Linux, and Windows machines successfully
- ping requests from the router, Linux, and Windows machine are seen by the Mac (via tcpdump)
- the Mac sees its own replies being sent in response to requests (via tcpdump)
- the other machines do not see the replies (Linux via tcpdump, Windows via Wireshark, router via ping)
- the router sees the proper entries in its ARP table for the Mac
- the Mac reports no errors related to networking in its system logs
- the Mac reports itself as being connected properly to the wireless network

The problem seems to randomly happen to the Mac. I've had it happen when doing heavy downloading. I've had it happen while doing no activity at all (reading a web page, which yes, may mean something is happening in the background).

This is a Late 2008 15-inch MacBook Pro with built-in AirPort (0x14E4, 0x8D), BroadCom BCM43xx 1.0 firmware.

Any ideas?